# Ожидание и обработка сигнала (Си, Линукс)

Tags: c, linux

нужно чтобы дочерний процесс дождался сигнала от предка и выполнил свои функции. подскажите, почему сигнал не обрабатывается (сообщение о порождении не выводится) и как сделать ожидание получения сигнала?

```
void myhandler(int sign){
printf("Процесс-родитель %d породил процесс-наследника %d", getppid(), getpid());
}

int main (void){
printf("Текущий процесс %d, родитель %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
proc = fork();
if (proc == 0){
    //не знаю как сделать ожидание сигнала
    signal(SIGUSR1, myhandler); 
    }
    else{   
    kill(proc, SIGUSR1);
    printf("родитель завершил работу \n");
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Перед `kill` явно просится ожидание какого-то синхронизатора, который будет спускаться в дочернем процессе, после установки обработчика, а после `kill` - `wait` для дочернего процесса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, Вы непонятно как получаете PID потомка. Значение выражение `1+getpid()` не гарантировано даст его PID. Правильное его значение уже содержится в переменной `proc`.

Сделайте просто паузу с помощью `sleep` перед посылкой сигнала (положим, 2 сек) в родительском процессе и, положим, 5 сек  в дочернем после регистрации хендлера.

Comment: @mikillskegg, ну если убрать kill и signal, то всегда (не было еще по-другому), pid потомка у меня = предок+1.
А sleep работает, без вопросов, но задание именно через сигналы сделать.

Comment: Это может быть, но это не гарантировано. Теоретически между запуском родителя и запуском дочернего другая другая программа может тоже что-то запустить и это что-то будет иметь PID на 1 больше, чем PID нашей родительской программы.

Comment: @mikillskegg, а что по коду: конкретно вызов и обработка сигнала верно написаны?

Comment: Это написано правильно, но Ваш способ получения дочернего PID - неправилен, поскольку может привести к очень неприятной ситуации, когда сигнал будет послан не тому процессу.

Comment: исправил здесь и в коде - результат не изменился: 
родитель есть, послал kill и завершился

Comment: Выложите новый код

Comment: если расставить sleep`ы, то все работает.
но не знаю, на сколько это корректно, т.к. надо чтобы дочерний процесс начинал работу только после получения сигнала

Comment: вместо sleep лучше родительскому процессу сигнал послать, после того, как установился листенер сигнала дочернего. (ну или просто в родителе sleep 0) по SIGUSR1 sleep вроде прекращается